# Surjectivity of global sections of sheaf of Kaehler differentials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, algebraic-curves, kahler-differentials

By a curve I mean a scheme of pure dimension $1$.
Let $C_1, C_2$ be a local complete intersection curve in $\mathbb{P}^3$ such that $C_1 \cap C_2$ are finitely many points. Assume further that  $C:=C_1 \cup C_2$ is a local complete intersection curve in $\mathbb{P}^3$ as well. Is it true  that the natural morphism $H^0(\Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}^3}|_C) \to H^0(\Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}^3}|_{C_1})$ is surjective?

Comment: Are you aware that $\Omega ^1_{\mathbb{P}^3}{}^{}_{|C}$ embeds into $\mathcal{O}_C(-1)^4$? In general (e.g. if your curves are reduced) both spaces will be zero.